# Prove or disprove $[[x] + x] = [2x]$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

I tried to prove that through giving a value which is floating-point but I have to solve this using letters like the proving  that if $n^2$ is odd , then $n$ is odd when I say $n=2k+1$.

The question is, prove or disprove: For all real numbers $x$ and $y$, $[[x] + x] = [2x]$ where $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Thank you for response.

Comment: Take $x=0.5$, then $[x]=0$, $[[x]+x]=[x]=0$, $[2x]=1$.

Comment: You can _never_ prove by example! Only disprove! What is the meaning of $[x]$? Rounding? What kind of rounding?

Comment: What does $y$ have to do with it? You say "for all real numbers $x$ and $y$ but then $yR is never mentioned again.

Comment: Thanks your for suggestions but I want to disprove it  without using numebr values , how can I do it in that way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how to construct a counter-example as follows.

Set $x = n + \epsilon$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\epsilon \in [0, 1)$. Then we have $[x] = [n + \epsilon] = n$.

Looking at the L.H.S. we have

$$
[[x] + x] = [2n + \epsilon] = 2n\ .
$$

On the R.H.S. we have

$$
[2x] = [2n + 2\epsilon] = \begin{cases}
2n\ &\quad 0 < \epsilon < 0.5 \\
2n + 1\ &\quad 0.5 \geq \epsilon < 1
\end{cases}
$$

So the original equality only holds if $\epsilon < 0.5$, so choosing any $\epsilon \geq 0.5$ will break the equality.

If we try $\epsilon = 0.5$, we see immediately that $[[0.5] + 0.5] = [0 + 0.5] = 0 \neq [2(0.5)] = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is false. You can thus not prove it, only disprove it. You can disprove statements by example. I suggest trying $x=0.6$.

Comment: Why would you assume $[x]$ means rounded to the nearest integer when it says in the question $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$? In other words, $[x] = \mathrm{floor}(x)$.

Comment: If you take $[x] = \mathrm{floor}(x)$ then $x = 0.6$ still works as a counterexample, since we have $[[0.6] + 0.6] = [0 + 0.6] = [0.6] = 0 \neq [2(0.6)] = [1.2] = 1$.

Comment: Because I somehow missed that part. Thanks for pointing it out, I fixed the reply.